# When is it appropriate to use linear regression vs. Naive Bayes?

Tags: regression, probability, correlation, bayesian

Based on my readings, it appears as though linear regression lends itself to cases where both X and Y are numerical and you have a large sample size, whereas Bayes is better for categorical variables with a small sample size.

Is there a criteria for scenario type?

My scenario in this case is measuring my own tiredness level everyday, and seeing if that correlates with whether I had breakfast that day, or the noisiness level at night.

I plan to have a new intervention every week and A/B test to see if there's a high correlation or not (eg only breakfast every other day).

I was trying to use Bayesian statistics to analyze my data, eg P(tired | breakfast), but the calculations became trickier when I had continuous variables like P(time it takes to fall asleep | noise level).

What is the best method for evaluating correlation between different variables and my tiredness levels if I am making interventions?

Comment: How do you measure tiredness? Usually what exactly is your response variable? Naive Bayes is primarily a classifier while linear regression is a... regression methodology; did you mean to say logistic regression?

Comment: Tiredness is measured on a scale of 1-5 with 0.25 increments. I was going to use Gaussian naive bayes in a similar way as linear regression by calculating the probabilities to find the max variable that influences tiredness the most.